# Python: url encoding with raw bracket []

Tags: python, python-requests, urlencode

Want final encoded url part as: `[%22AS%22]`

I tried:

`["AS"]` creates `%5B%22AS%22%5D`

`/["AS"/]` creates `%2F%5B%22AS%22%2F%5D`

```
baseUrl = "https://www.example.com/api"
params=(('id','/["AS"/]'))
requests.request("GET",baseUrl,params=params,headers=headers,cookies=cookies,allow_redirects=True,timeout=timeout,proxies=proxies,)
```

Any idea? I don't want to create new URL, rather change in `params` value (see below example).

Comment: Can you add a bit more clarity about what exactly you are trying to do? I'm not sure what your input is here.

Comment: @AmitSingh, added.

Comment: So you want to url encode it as "[%22AS%22]" if I'm not wrong, right?

Comment: @AmitSingh, yes, right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own URL but it should not be that difficult.

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote

baseUrl = "https://www.example.com/api"
params=[('id','["AS"]')]

param_str = "&".join([param[0]+"="+quote(param[1], safe='[]') for param in params])

req = requests.Request("GET", baseUrl, params=param_str)

# Just to check and verify
prepared_req = req.prepare()
print(prepared_req.url) # Prints 'https://www.example.com/api?id=[%22AS%22]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using urlencode

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
query_params = urlencode({"id": ["As"]})
url = "{}?{}".format('https://www.example.com/api', query_params)
print(url)
```